# React: Render new row every 4th column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I'm using `react` and I want to `render` a new row every 4th column.

My code:

```
function Product(props) {
  const content = props.products.map((product) => (
        <div className="row" key={product.id}>       
          <article key={product.id} className="col-md-3"></article>
        </div> )
  );
  return (
    <div>
        {content}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I tried with the approach by passing in a condition that looked like this:

`if (product.id % 4 == 1)`, around the columns, but it doesn't work...

This is what I want to happen:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
<div class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Group your products into rows of (at most) 4 elements, i.e.

   `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] => [ [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8 ] ]`
2. Iterate over the groups to generate rows, and in an inner loop iterate over the items to display columns

To calculate the number of rows, given 4 items per row, use `Math.ceil(props.products.length / 4)`. Then create an array of rows. Given 2 rows (for 8 items): `Array(2)`. Since you can't `map` an array of uninitialized elements, you can use spread syntax: `[...Array(2)]` which returns `[ undefined, undefined ]`.

Now you can map these `undefined` entries into rows: for each row take 4 elements from products: `[ undefined, undefined ].map( (row, idx) => props.products.slice(idx * 4, idx * 4 + 4) ) )` (**edit note** changed to `slice` since `splice` mutates the original array). The result is an array of arrays (rows of items).

You can iterate over the rows, and inside each iteration iterate over the items in given row.

https://jsfiddle.net/dya52m8y/2/

```
const Products = (props) => {
    // array of N elements, where N is the number of rows needed
    const rows = [...Array( Math.ceil(props.products.length / 4) )];
    // chunk the products into the array of rows
    const productRows = rows.map( (row, idx) => props.products.slice(idx * 4, idx * 4 + 4) ); );
    // map the rows as div.row
    const content = productRows.map((row, idx) => (
        <div className="row" key={idx}>    
          // map products in the row as article.col-md-3
          { row.map( product => <article key={product} className="col-md-3">{ product }</article> )}
        </div> )
    );
    return (
        <div>
          {content}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand what's going on here. Can't get your code to work even when I modified it...

Comment: @maverick edited the answer to explain the concepts. One important change is `slice` instead of `splice` which may have caused some problems. If it works for you in the fiddle, but doesn't in your implementation, please follow up with a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @pawel this should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer is inaccurate as you can't having the same row with the children if ur parent tag is closed. Thanks pawel for the answer. very nice code over there

Comment: Hi. Look Array( Math.ceil(props.products.length / 4) will always give empty

Answer (score 12):

write it like this:

```
function Product(props) {
  let content = [];
  props.products.forEach((product, i) =>{
      if((i+1) % 4 == 0){
        content.push(
          <div className="row" key={product.id}>       
            <article key={product.id} className="col-md-3"></article>
          </div>
        )
      }else{
          content.push(<article key={product.id} className="col-md-3"></article>);
      }
  });
  return (
    <div>
        {content}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hm... I see! But now there's 3 rows but only 1 column in each row...? Missing something?

Comment: didn't get you properly, can you show any image or somehow, whats the result you expecting and what you are getting by this ??

Comment: 1 Row > Column Column Column Column
2 Row > Column Column Column Column and so on and fourth

Comment: got it, check the updated answer :), in this case we can use map because we need to return something for each element :)

Comment: Hm, every column gets their own row... I want 4 columns in each row. If the row has 4 columns, it should create a new row.

Comment: check this fiddle, this is what you want https://jsfiddle.net/zbeb5yz7/ ?? if yes then you can modify above code.

Answer (score 5):

The nice thing about Bootstrap is that you can keep all the `col*` in a *single* `row`, and then insert a full-width `div` every 4 columns to force the wrap. These keeps it simpler and you don't have to chunk the data.

Here's what the React render looks like:

```
render() {
    let columns=[];
    this.props.items.forEach((item,idx) => {

        // push column
        columns.push(
            <div className="col-sm py-3" key={idx}>
                Content
            </div>
        )

        // force wrap to next row every 4 columns
        if ((idx+1)%4===0) {columns.push(<div className="w-100"></div>)}
    })


    return (
        <div className="row">
        {columns}
        </div>
    )            
}
```

**Demo:** https://www.codeply.com/go/VMV26jhHFz

Note: In **Bootstrap 4**, use `<div className="w-100"></div>` as shown above. In **Bootstrap 3**, use `<div className="clearfix"></div>` to force the columns to wrap every *n*.

Answer (score 4):

You want to wrap new row for each 4 columns, right?

Try this

```js
render() {
  const products = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
  let rowContents = [];
  const contents = products.reduce((acc, p, i) => {
   rowContents.push(<div key={i} className="col col-md-3">Col {p}</div>);
   if (i % 4 === 3) {
    acc.push(<div className="row">{rowContents}</div>);
    rowContents = [];
   }
   return acc;
  },[])
       contents.push(<div className="row">{rowContents}</div>);

  return (
   <div>
   {contents}
   </div>
  )
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
render() {

    function toChunkArray(myArray: any, chunkSize: any): any {
        var results = [];

        while (myArray.length) {
            results.push(myArray.splice(0, chunkSize));
        }

        return results;
    }

    let chunkedArraysOfColSize = toChunkArray(myList, 3);

    return (
        <div className="row">
            {
                chunkedArraysOfColSize.map( (colSizeArray, index) =>
                    <div className="col-sm-4" key={index.toString()}>
                        {colSizeArray.map((o, i) =>
                            <NameOfComponent key={o.Id} obj={o} />
                        )}
                    </div>
                )
            }
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a single row and all columns (col-md-3) can go inside that. To achieve multiple row effect after each 4th column, you can set style to every 4th column like this-

```
<div className="col-md-3" style={{clear: (index != 0 && index % 4 == 0) ? 'both' : 'none'}}></div>
```

This will achieve the same result as having multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

All of the current answers don't really seem [Keep It Simple, Stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) as they are focusing on just printing one set of items one time and not taking into account further processing of rows with differing amounts of items. The following answer uses typescript but could be simply implemented in vanilla JS. I'm also using `lodash chunk` as a convenience, though your own chunking method would be simple to add if required.

```
import * as _ from 'lodash'

export enum flexChunkOptions {
    col1 = 12,
    col2 = 6,
    col3 = 4,
    col4 = 3,
    col6 = 2,
    col12 = 1
}


export const chunkIntoFlexgrid = (numbOfItemsInRow: flexChunkOptions, arrayOfItems: ArrayLike<any>) => {
    return _.chunk(arrayOfItems, numbOfItemsInRow)
}
```

In the above we are creating an enum which has all of our bootstrap column definitions that are divisible by 12. This is done simply so we can use the corresponding col definition in our template for ease. We are expecting to receive an array of items of any type (note for ts users `ArrayLike<any>` is better for type safety than `any`). After which we return back a chunked down array probably something like `[[1,2,3], [1,2,3]]` if we choose `col-3`.

```
const myArrOfItems = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

{chunkIntoFlexgrid(flexChunkOptions.col3, mySetOfItems).map((el, i) => {
                        return <div key={ `row-${ i }` } className={ `row` }>
                            {
                                el.map(item => item)
                            }
                        </div>
                    })
```

In our template we can simply call our connivence method and provide how we would like our rows to be generated and simply use our outer `el` variable to work with indvidual elements.

Here's a link to the [lodash chunk documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#chunk)