# How to automatically arrange cards in rows and columns?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Im trying to create a interactive user interface in ReactJS, using react-bootstrap. Im using cards and CardGroup. I need a way to automatically arrange the cards in new rows. Something like three cards per row, and if I have more than three, create a new row for the 4th card.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {Card,CardGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';
    import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';
    const Items = ({items}) => {
      return (
    <>
    <container>
    <row>
    <CardGroup>
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>

      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Title>{item.NOME}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">{item.CATEGORIA}</Card.Subtitle>
        <Card.Text>
        {item.DESCRICAO}
        </Card.Text>
        <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
        <Card.Link href="#">Another Link</Card.Link>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
          ))}
        </CardGroup>
        </row>
        </container>
    </>
        )
    };

    export default Items
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Comment: Updated with code.

Comment: This will help you finding the right approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42391499/react-render-new-row-every-4th-column

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array with groups of 3 cards and then iterate over them:

```
const arr = var x = arr.reduce((item, key, index) => (index % 3 == 0 ? item.push([key]) : item[item.length-1].push(key)) && item, []);

const Items = ({items}) => (
  <>
    <container>
      {arr.map(group => (
        <row>
          <CardGroup>
            {group.map(card => (
              <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
                <Card.Body>
                  <Card.Title>{item.NOME}</Card.Title>
                  <Card.Subtitle className="mb-2 text-muted">{item.CATEGORIA}</Card.Subtitle>
                  <Card.Text>{item.DESCRICAO}</Card.Text>
                  <Card.Link href="#">Card Link</Card.Link>
                  <Card.Link href="#">Another Link</Card.Link>
                </Card.Body>
              </Card>
            ))}
          </CardGroup>
        </row>
      ))}
    </container>
  </>
);
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should work...